# analyze outlook calendar data in spss

Tags: spss

I downloaded Conference Room Usage from outlook.
I want to know

- How busy are the conference rooms?
- What are the hot times?
- Who are the super users?
- Who are not the super users?
- How many recurrent meetings take place.

This issue i'm having is that I need the duration between the "StartTime" and the "EndTime"; but they are currently strings!
start        end          starttime  endtime
1/1/2014    1/1/2014    5:00:00 PM  5:00:00 PM

Also, it's likely safe to assume that StartTimes and EndTimes do not straddle two days, but perhaps I want to check for this.
Perhaps conversion to a 24-hour clock might help; "Duration" is then "EndTime" - "StartTime".  How can i convert back to a 12-hour clock for the uninitiated.  Finally, I need the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc) an event falls on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can mostly be accomplished through the wizard.

some sudo code that should do the trick would be

```
COMPUTE Start=number(StartDate, ADATE10).
VARIABLE LEVEL  Start (SCALE).
FORMATS Start (ADATE10).
VARIABLE WIDTH  Start(10).
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE starttimetest=number(StartTime, TIME8).
VARIABLE LEVEL  starttimetest (SCALE).
FORMATS starttimetest (TIME8).
VARIABLE WIDTH  starttimetest(8).
EXECUTE.
compute teststartadd=start+starttimetest.

DO if index(starttime,'PM') gt 0 and subs(starttime,1,2) ne '12' .
COMPUTE Realstart=datesum(teststartadd,12,'hours').
ELSE.
COMPUTE REALstart=TESTstartADD.
END IF.

COMPUTE End=number(EndDate, ADATE10).
VARIABLE LEVEL  End (SCALE).
FORMATS End (ADATE10).
VARIABLE WIDTH  End(10).
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE endtimetest=number(endTime, TIME8).
VARIABLE LEVEL  endtimetest (SCALE).
FORMATS endtimetest (TIME8).
VARIABLE WIDTH  endtimetest(8).
EXECUTE.
compute testendadd=end+endtimetest.
DO if index(endtime,'PM') gt 0 and subs(endtime,1,2) ne '12' .
COMPUTE RealEnd=datesum(testendadd,12,'hours').
ELSE.
COMPUTE REALEND=TESTENDADD.
END IF.
exe.
delete vars Start
starttimetest
teststartadd
End
endtimetest
testendadd.
exe.

formats RealEnd RealStart(datetime23).
compute Length=datedif(realend,realstart,'hours').
if length > 12 check=1.
freq check.
compute StartWkDay=XDATE.WKDAY(realstart).
compute EndWkDay=XDATE.WKDAY(realEnd).
string StartDayText EndDayText(a8).
```

you'll have to convert using something like
     *if XDATE.WKDAY(realstart)=1  startdaytext="Sunday".